prometheuspemotewrite Exporter with container-based Lambda not exporting metrics to cortex
I'm trying to use the ADOT collector to send metrics from my container-based Lambda function to a Cortex instance using the prometheuspemotewrite exporter. However, I can't see any metrics appearing in Prometheus/Grafana.
Here's my setup:
/src/otel-config.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:

exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: "http://cortexendpoint.com/api/v1/push/custom"
    add_metric_suffixes: false
    external_labels:
      accountname: something
    target_info:
      enabled: false
    tls:
      insecure: true

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheusremotewrite]

Related parts in my Dockerfile (this part of the dockerfile I thought could be helpful):
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim

ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY ./aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-24-0-0fe7e12f-1687-4b13-b87b-23ef71e028b8.zip ./
RUN unzip -o aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-24-0-0fe7e12f-1687-4b13-b87b-23ef71e028b8.zip -d /opt \
    && rm aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-24-0-0fe7e12f-1687-4b13-b87b-23ef71e028b8.zip


COPY ./src ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src

requirements I'm installing using pip (only related ones)
opentelemetry-sdk==1.24.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-http==1.24.0
opentelemetry-distro==0.45b0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp==1.24.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-aws-lambda==0.45b0
opentelemetry-exporter-prometheus-remote-write==0.45b0

Environment Variables:
    AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER: /opt/otel-instrument
    OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE: /var/task/src/otel-config.yaml
    OPENTELEMETRY_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL: debug

Part of my infrastructure related to entrypoint and command:
ImageConfig:
  EntryPoint:
    - /usr/local/bin/python
    - -m
    - awslambdaric
  Command:
    - src.api.app.lambda_handler

Some of logs I thought could be useful:
{
    "level": "info",
    "ts": 1719013929.4558766,
    "caller": "otlpreceiver@v0.98.0/otlp.go:152",
    "msg": "Starting HTTP server",
    "kind": "receiver",
    "name": "otlp",
    "data_type": "metrics",
    "endpoint": "0.0.0.0:4318"
}
{
    "level": "debug",
    "ts": 1719013929.41899,
    "caller": "exporter@v0.98.0/exporter.go:273",
    "msg": "Beta component. May change in the future.",
    "kind": "exporter",
    "data_type": "metrics",
    "name": "prometheusremotewrite"
}
{
    "level": "debug",
    "ts": 1719013935.0473416,
    "logger": "telemetryAPI.Listener",
    "msg": "Event processed",
    "event": {
        "time": "2024-06-21T23:52:15.020Z",
        "type": "platform.runtimeDone",
        "record": {
            "metrics": {
                "durationMs": 1991.457,
                "producedBytes": 14260
            },
            "requestId": "110c4917-6fa8-413c-b5bc-b72c2365d87d",
            "spans": [
                {
                    "durationMs": 1990.988,
                    "name": "responseLatency",
                    "start": "2024-06-21T23:52:13.029Z"
                },
                {
                    "durationMs": 0.084,
                    "name": "responseDuration",
                    "start": "2024-06-21T23:52:15.020Z"
                },
                {
                    "durationMs": 0.188,
                    "name": "runtimeOverhead",
                    "start": "2024-06-21T23:52:15.020Z"
                }
            ],
            "status": "success",
            "tracing": {
                "spanId": "58b9e5c7e7a04afe",
                "type": "X-Amzn-Trace-Id",
                "value": "Root=1-66761228-4f2fb057752REMOVEDneage=9ac6c4b9:0"
            }
        }
    }
}

So the problem is that the OpenTelemetry collector appears to be running and processing metrics, but I don't see any metrics in Prometheus/Grafana. There are no explicit errors in the logs, and connectivity seems fine.
I remember with the zip based lambda I was able to see some export failed: 404 (or something like that), but in my setup even by passing a wrong endpoint, I'm not getting any error (not sure what I'm missing here).
I couldn't also find any helpful example working with OTEL collector and container-based Lambda functions.
Resources that I mostly started my work:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77625836


